# Can i use eclipse to connect MS sql database and select data out?

Tags: eclipse

I am new in eclipse,i wan to to develop a app using phonegap wizard based on CSS,JS,HTML5 languages.
my question is

Can I Connect MS SQL database and return table in eclipse?how?
(If possible make the code by the type language i using, if cant also can provide me some information by link or something)

thank you for answer

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Open the 'Database Development' perspective, add a new connection to the DB in the Data Source Explorer, and away you go.

Comment: Hi, @artbristol Can you please provide any link or code to explain how to connect to SQl from phonegap apps. I am facing similar issue. It will really help me. As phonegap only uses JS, HTML and CSS; is there a way in JS to call MS SQl?